# Problems trying to load Setup.exe in windows xp though my batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp, setup.exe

When I try and run my setup.exe file from the location `C:\DMSDMSOffice1-16\Setup.exe` it always conflicts with the `setup.exe` in the system32 folder. But as an example the `:Measurement` part works perfect. How do I get around this? Here is part of my script. Also I'm making this script for use on a Windows XP Pro machine.

```
:Meausurment
cls
cd "Tiger\Measurment Computer CD"
Install.exe
goto:options

:DMS
cls
cd DMSOffice1-16
SETUP.EXE

goto:options
```

Comment: I tried doing that but still no success.

Comment: Remove the `cls` from both spots and you will see the error messages. Also, place a `pause` command after the cd lines and look for error messages that give you a clue as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:DMS
cls
cd DMSOFF~1
SETUP.EXE

goto:options
```

What is your result?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
:DMS
cls
c:
cd C:\DMSDMSOffice1-16
SETUP.EXE

goto:options
```

Always best to go to the correct directory. Probably `PUSHD` would be a better option in any case.